# JQuery replacing css class attribute of all table cells in a row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the class attribute of all the cells within a given row in a table.  Here is what I've attempted but while I don't get an exception, it doesn't work either.

Here is a sample of the current html for the rows/cells is as follows.

```
    <tr id="rowid-1234">
        <td class="tblistred">20-400 Silver  Metal Closure</td>
        <td class="tblistred">Tecno, LLC</td>                          
        <td class="tblistred">Closure</td>
        <td class="tblistred">New Item</td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my script:

```
    var rowId = "#rowid-" + response.id;
    $(rowId).each(function (index) {
        $(this).children('td').addClass('tblist');
    });
```

**UPDATE**
OK, I changed it to this, but it still isn't setting the class.

```
   alert($(rowId).find("td:first-child").text());
   $(rowId).children('td').addClass('tblist');
```

I added the alert to ensure that I have the correct row, and it confirms that I do.

**SOLUTION**
  I had to Remove the class that was already there

```
  $(rowId + ' td').removeClass('tblistred').addClass('tblist');
```

Comment: This kind of error should be caught with syntax highlighting. Notepad is not a good source editor.

Comment: @Chad Or in code preview on StackOverflow...

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, but that variable declaration I added was just typed in as I posted my question. I've edited the question.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", are you sure that the class isn't being applied to your `td`s? Maybe the CSS just doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: No, I've checked the class on the td's after running the script.  I should point out that the class is set on the td's already, and I'm trying to change it. Perhaps addClass doesn't replace the existing class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the existing class from the td before adding the class.

I found the answer [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Here is what I ended up with.

```
    $(rowId + ' td').removeClass('tblistred').addClass('tblist');
```

Comment: In fact, your question was inaccurate: you were not only trying to add a class to the cells. You wanted to remove one and replace it with the new. I'm glad it worked :-)

Comment: Yes it was. I up-voted all answers, as they were correct for the question as I had asked.  However, I wanted to create the answer so others who find themselves here can clearly see the solution.

Comment: Nice, but please also update your question and answer, as part of the question is only revealed in your answer...

Answer (score 3):

As the code highlighting shows, you have mismatched quotes:

```
var rowID = '#row-' + response.id; // <-- see matching single quotes
```

---

Also, you should only have one element with a given `id`, so calling `each`on it doesn't really make sense. If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, that could be another reason why this would fail. If not, you can just do `$(rowId).children('td').addClass('tblist');`

Comment: I tried this, $(rowId).children('td').addClass('tblist');, but it didn't work.  See my updates to my question.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$(rowID + ' td').addClass('tblist');
```

Comment: That was suggested by @Doozer Blake. I tried it but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could likely do this with just:

```
$('#row-" + response.Id + " td").addClass('tblist');
```